# Differential Equation Confusion Homework

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In solving the differential equation using the method of undetermined coefficients for the equation: y'' - 2y' + 2y = x + $e^x$, I first solved for the auxiliary equation:

$r^2$ - 2r + 2 = 0. Using the quadratic equation, you get the roots of 1 ± i. This would give the general solution of y = $e^x$($C_1$ cosβ + $C_2$ sinβ.

Next, since G(x) = x + $e^x$, this is where my confusion happens. There is a textbook example of when G(x) is additive, you separate them. In this case, it would be

Ax + B + C = x

$y_p$ = Ax

$y_p'$ = A

$y_p''$ = 0

And,
$e^x$ = $e^x$

$y_p$ = $e^x$

$y_p'$ = $e^x$

$y_p''$ = $e^x$

And finally superposition principle, the solution would be $y_c$ + $y_p1$ + $y_p2$

But seeing one solution, it was to use A$e^x$ + Bx + C which provided the correct answer. I am just confused on why you would use A$e^x$ + Bx + C instead of splitting them up. Is there a way to get the correct solution by splitting?

Comment: You'll need to actually think backwards - what function, when you take two derivatives, gives a linear function?

Comment: I think you meant $1\pm i$ where you typed $1\pm2i$

Comment: when the derivative of the function = 0?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, you are right. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.math.mcgill.ca/jakobson/courses/ma261/lecture12.pdf that may help you. There are two example with forcing term $x$ and $e^x$.